# c# bmi calculator NaN issue when I enter weight and height

Tags: c#-2.0

I enter the weight and height and end up getting Nan as a result for BMI. Thank you for your help and consideration on this question

```
double height = 0.0;
double weight = 0.0;
double bmi = height / weight;
double bmi = height / weight;
Console.Write("Enter your height in m:");
height = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Enter your weight in kg:");
weight = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is:{0}", Math.Round(bmi,4));
bmi = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Please tell me you don't *actually* write all of your code on one damn line.

Comment: The code editor was not allowing me to code it correctly. However, I reposted it now. Thanks again for anyone that can assist me.

Comment: That's funny, because it works for thousands of people every day, did for me. Please verify the code in the question looks like you intend, and delete the comments which contain code.

Answer (score 0):

You're calculating `bmi` before `height` and `weight` have been assigned. They have their initial value of 0, so you have a divide-by-zero situation, which results in NaN:

```
double height = 0.0;
double weight = 0.0;
double bmi = height / weight;
```

`bmi` doesn't get automatically updated. You need to assign `height` and `weight` *first*, and *then* calculate `bmi`.

```
Console.Write("Enter your height in m:");
double height = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Enter your weight in kg:");
double weight = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

double bmi = height / weight;
Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is:{0}", Math.Round(bmi,4));
```